# Have a number as identifier for a json

Tags: python, json

I have a (python) json that currently looks like this

`{"templates":{"Main Screen":0,"dummy":1}}`

what I want to have is

`{"templates":{0:"Main Screen",1:"dummy"}}`

but json would not decode it anymore

```
self.fileData=json.loads(self.VDfile.readlines()[0])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 15 (char 14)
```

any way around this?

thank you

Comment: json keys have to be strings, they can't be integers.

Comment: Would `{"templates":{"0":"Main Screen", "1":"dummy"}}` be acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it seems like you really want is

```
{"templates":["Main Screen", "dummy"]}
```

In python, you can do like `templates[0]` or `templates[1:]`, which is a better API than `templates["0"]` or `templates.get("0")`.